# how to upload the result CSV file to one drive from JMETER tool

Tags: jmeter, onedrive

we have a requirement to upload the result file (CSV) from Jmeter to one drive . Is there a way to do that from jmeter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [OneDrive REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/?view=odsp-graph-online) in order to manipulate the files in OneDrive directly from JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers

Check out [Upload or replace the contents of a DriveItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_put_content?view=odsp-graph-online) article to learn more about properly forming a [PUT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT) request which will upload the file of your choice to the OneDrive storage

Check out [REST API Testing - How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right) article for general concept of invoking REST API requests from JMeter.